# How to query a bigquery view from bigquery APIs

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, google-api, google-bigquery

I have a view in bigquery which contains fields from different datasets and tables, Now I would like to query this view through my google script. What is correct way of doing that.

Actually Currently I have created a separate table in bigquery and querying the table instead of view but I need view as view will get updated when the dependency tables will be updated.

If I am using the table, It is working fine but in case of view I am getting below error:

```
Exception: Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found.
```

Bigquery api's to return the result of query.

```
  try {
    var job = BigQuery.newJob();
    var config = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
    var queryConfig = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationQuery();
    queryConfig.setQuery(sql);
    queryConfig.setMaximumBillingTier(5);

    config.setQuery(queryConfig);
    job.setConfiguration(config);

    var jobid = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectNumber).jobReference;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, jobid.jobId);

  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
    return;
  }


  // Check on status of the Query Job : MONTHLY 
  while (queryResults.getJobComplete() == false) {
    try {
      queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, queryResults.jobId);
      //queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectNumber, job.id);
    }
    catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      Browser.msgBox(err);
      return;
    }
  }
  return queryResults;
```

If I comment out my first try clause and use below one

```
 try {
   var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
   queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000);
   queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
    //Browser.msgBox(queryResults);
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
    return;
  }
```

then It starts giving me

```
Exception: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 3 or higher required.
```

Comment: There should be no difference between view and table like queries all should be valid SQL queries. Maybe your error is coming from elsewhere.

Comment: @Pentium10 , I agree but I am getting this error only when I change the table name to view name

Comment: Post the SQL maybe there is an issue there.

Comment: @Pentium10 sql is fine as I am getting the output when i paste the same query in bigquery console.

SELECT SUM(finalprice)/100.0 FROM [Insights.redemption] WHERE role = 'customer' AND (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(ordercreatedat * 1000 + 19800000, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2016-05-11' AND '2016-05-12')

Comment: @Pentium10 Actually, I have to add the unlimited billing tier when doing the above query in the console, Inside the code I did it as 5, can that be the issue but I tried increasing it upto 10.. no success

Comment: @Pentium10 I tried the other way of querying ... you can see it at the end of my question.. Please tell me if it strikes you something

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the '[configuration.query.maximumBillingTier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.maximumBillingTier)' property isn't getting set when you are inserting the job. The method of using 'JobConfigurationQuery' and other classes seems to have been abandoned as there is no mention of them in the current docs, and I needed to resort to using the Wayback Machine to [find them](https://web.archive.org/web/20130118041702/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_bigquery).

The most recently available [document](https://web.archive.org/web/20131112131503/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_bigquery_v2_schema_jobconfigurationquery) from 11/12/2013 only defines getters and setters for a few configuration properties, and 'maximumBillingTier' isn't one of them.

I'd suggest manually setting the request properties as is done in the usage examples from the [current documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery), rather than relying on the "old" object constructors, as they seem to only be left around for compatibility purposes and are incomplete.

The reason a view would require a higher billing tier versus a table, by the way, is because a view is only a [logical table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views) and the queries which define the view must be re-executed when the view itself is queried.